# GCD of two numbers using Racket

Tags: racket

When I use racket to define a function that find the gcd of two integers,

```
(define (gcd a b)
    (cond
         [(> a b) (gcd b a-b)]
         [(< a b) (gcd a b-a)]
         [else a]))
```

But,

> a-b: unbound identifier in module in: a-b

I don't know what to do.
Why is that happen?

Comment: In Scheme `b-a` and `a-b` are variables, they are not expressions involving two variables. You subtract with the procedure `-`. eg. `(- a b)`

Answer (score 1):

Since Racket doesn't recognize infix operation, changing the operation to a prefix expression works fine :)

```
(define (gcd a b)
    (cond
         [(> a b) (gcd b (- a b))]
         [(< a b) (gcd a (- b a))]
         [else a]))
```